# Missions 2017 Worlds Master Pass challenge

Tags: league-of-legends

According to website [surrender@20](http://www.surrenderat20.net/2017/09/red-post-collection-worlds-2017_21.html#more) to be able to get final loot (ChampionshipnAshe Golden Chroma and 2017 Golden Championship Ward) they offer the 2017 Worlds Master Pass.

[image]

In the table above, they say that the price of Master Pass will decrease over time.

So, is the Master Pass free or do I need to buy it? If I really need to buy it, in which currency are the costs mentioned in the table? IP or RP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to buy it with RP. The prices listed in the chart are in RP.

The reason it gets cheaper each week is because quests expire at the end of the week, so the later you buy the pass the less benefit you're getting out of it.